# Exporting over 30k products to .csv

Tags: magento2, products, export

I need to get a .csv file of all products (over 30000) from a Magento 2 store. Problem is when I start the export from backend, Magento dies after a few minutes and throws 500 error.

Any idea how can I make this happen with such a large number of products without Magento dying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue with my store (> 60k products). I used this tool to export the catalog: https://www.atensoftware.com/p187.php

(* I'm not the developer of the tool)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the export in cron mode. It will add the job in cron after that run below command

```
php bin/magento queue:consumer:start exportProcessor
```

This command initiates the export processor consumer, which is responsible for handling product exports through the Magento message queue system.